# InstallShield LE is not working in vs2013 in windows 8.1

Tags: visual-studio-2013, installshield, windows-8.1, setup-project

I am working in Visual Studio 2013 on Windows 8.1 .

I have windows service project, for that i want to create a setup project.

I am trying to add install shield limited edition project.

[image]

When i am clicking on OK button. Nothing happend, nnly setup1 named folder created in my solution folder.

What should i do to fix this bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Visual Studio 2013, IDE showing "Enable InstallSheild Limited Edition", it means you have not installed InstallSheild yet. Download InstallShield from [here](http://learn.flexerasoftware.com/content/IS-EVAL-InstallShield-Limited-Edition-Visual-Studio). After download it install installSeild and run visual studio as administrator. Then add InstallSheild template to your project, it will work now.

This [article](http://blogs.flexerasoftware.com/installtalk/2012/11/using-installshield-to-create-an-installation-that-installs-windows-services.html) will guide through rest process.